# Local user creation in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, reinstall

On my old Windows 10, I had a user Karl along with a directory called "Karl" under c:\users. Had to do a reinstall. Now when I create a user using the MS Accounts in Control Panel, the entry that appears under c:\users is "dance." This corresponds to the first five letters of my email address. It does not create a directory listing called "Karl".  This seems nuts. Why does MS do this?

I tried changing "dance" to "Karl" but this failed.  Shall I now just transfer all my previous entries from c:\users\Karl to c:\users\dance?  Will this work?

Comment: This is a simple problem to solve.  Disconnect the account from A Microsoft Account.  You will be provided a prompt for a new user profile name.  Enter your desire name.  Once you logout and log back into the account connect the account to your Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect from internet. Then, in "settings->Family&other users" you can create a local user without MS Account. The user's directory name will correspond to the User's name.

Another way to achieve the same is: When creating a new user, you can select "I don't have the person's sign-in information", and on the next screen "Add a user without a Microsoft account".

For more information, [see this article](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/should-you-use-local-or-microsoft-account-windows-10/)

Comment: The article you refer to is outdated and isn’t applicable to current versions of Windows 10